# Вывести данные из таблицы MySQL в JTable

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Пытаюсь вывести из таблицы MySQL данные в таблицу JTable, вот код:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer;";
                statement.execute(sql);
                final ResultSet rec = statement.getResultSet();
                int rowCount = 0;
                while(rec.next()) {
                    model.setValueAt(rec.getString(0),rowCount,0);
                    model.setValueAt(rec.getString(1),rowCount,1);
                    model.setValueAt(rec.getString(2),rowCount,2);
                    model.setValueAt(rec.getString(3),rowCount,3);
                    rowCount++;
                }
```

Получаю ошибку :

> java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1.

Что не так с кодом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индекс столбца начинается с 1, а не с 0, что и говорит exception.

```
rec.getString(0)
              ^
```

[Из документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) `ResultSet`

> ```
> String getString(int columnIndex)
>                  throws SQLException
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Parameters**: columnIndex - the
>   first column is 1, the second is 2, ...

Comment: Разобрался! Ещё добавил строку model.addRow(new Object[0]);